# How to mock a nested Function in python having some parameters in it

Tags: pytest, pytest-mock

I'am new to pytest, I want to mock a function *toMockFunction* having parameter as **a** and **b** and these are initialized from system arguments in another .py file and its present inside a parent Function *nestFunction* So how to mock this *toMockFunction* from a pytest file?

```
# This Function is present in File A.py
def nestFunction():
    abc = 1
    returned_var = toMockFunction(a, b)
    return returned_var

# This Function is present in File B.py
def toMockFunction(a, b):
    data = pd.read_csv("a.csv")

    ### Some operations ###

    return data

# This Function is present in File test_A.py
def test_nestFunction():
    df = pd.read_csv("someFile.csv")
    mocker.patch('somepath.B.toMockFunction', return_value=df)
    output = nestFunction()
    pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df,output)

# Present in File A.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = sys.arg[1]
    b = sys.arg[2]
```

Here sys.arg[1] and sys.arg[2] are passed as parameters from run config tab

I tried the exact code but the error is - name 'a' and 'b' are not defined

i.e its not able to mock the nested function also its aking for the input parameters

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with `pytest`. The error as you describe states, `name 'a' and 'b' are not defined`. This much is true since the function definition has the following:

```
def nestFunction():
    abc = 1
    returned_var = toMockFunction(a, b)
```

At no point in this function is `a` or `b` defined, only `abc` is defined. Define `a` and `b` properly and you should get past this error.

Comment: Actually, as I mentioned that a, and b are system arguments and I'm accepting them from the Main Function itself, So the nestFunction should be able to read a, b and also the main function and nestFunction are present in the same file i.e A.py

Comment: they are not global variables and they are not present or defined in the same scope. the traceback is clear about what the issue is.